# Chart.js: how adjust position of legend?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

There is a chart in a scrollable (x) canvas. The legend is set to display at the top (must be). The canvas (div) can be much wider than the browser screen. Means the legend is only visible when the user views the beginning of the chart.
How can I change the x-position of the legend dependent of the scroll-position to keep it visible at all time?
Note: responsive for the whole chart is not an option.

```
<div id="chart-container" style="position:relative; width: 200px; overflow-x: scroll">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="height:35vh" ></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
    var chartData = {
        labels: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Testing",
                data: [10,30,20,10,40,50,70,100,30,20],
                borderColor: "blue",
            },
        ]
    };

    // Define the chart options
    var chartOptions = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: false,
        legend:{
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            align: 'start',
        } 
    };

    // Create the chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: chartData,
        options: chartOptions,
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your code or upload on stackblitz 

Comment: The only feasible possibility I see is to make an [HTML legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/html.html) and use CSS and/or javascript to position its container the way you want

Comment: thank you. one thing I don't understand (in the example you have linked): how to set the color of the legend box to the line color? boxSpan.style.background = item.borderColor; doesn't work!?

Comment: found it: boxSpan.style.background must be set to item.strokeStyle - this is really awkward ...

Comment: You have to set the background color in the dataset, there's probably nothing implicit. Look at the `Data` tab in the code snippet on that page. Or, yes, you can just use the `strokeStyle`, maybe `transparentize` it.